# What is the Chinese equivalent of “to pick up a girl” or “to hit on girls”?

Tags: phrase

How do you say "to pick up girls" in Chinese? I would like to say: I'm going to go and pick up some girls!

Disclaimer: Question inspired by https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/40214/what-is-the-japanese-equivalent-of-to-pick-up-a-girl-or-to-hit-on-girls

Comment: 修车, 这车你能修吗?(Can you pick up that girl?),

Comment: 撩妹 has become a very popular phrase recently; 泡妞 is another very common, well-known phrase that's been around longer.

Comment: @wolfrevo are you trying to protect the girls?

Comment: Just to let you know that most the answers mean hitting on girls and not being serious about it/ not looking for a relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head, I can think of 勾搭, 泡妞, 把妹 and 溝女

> **勾搭**
>
> http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/52068/
>
> [1] *pick up a lover*

*

> **溝女** (Cantonese slang)
>
> http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/20482/
>
> *pick up chicks; go out looking for women to chat up; dawdle away one's time with a girl; [slang] cruise (look for sexual partner)*
>
> [variants] *媾女, 勼女, 追女仔*
>
> *溝 is most probably a loanword from '(to) court'.*

*

> **泡妞** (Mandarin slang)
>
> *to pick up chicks; to go out looking for women to chat up; to chase skirts; to dawdle away one's time with girls |*
>
> http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/40924/

*

> **把妹** (Internet slang)
>
> *http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/58867/*
>
> *to chase girls; to pick up girls*

```
 I'm going to go and pick up some girls!
```

我要去泡妞 (Mandarin slang)

我要去溝女 (Cantonese slang)

我要去把妹 (web slang)

我要去勾搭女人 (literal) *"女人" can be replaced by 女孩 or 女生 in Mandarin and 女仔 in Cantonese*

Answer (score 0):

Looking for a one night stand you might say:

我今晚去约炮。

Good luck with that!

Answer (score 0):

A common internet slang word for this is 撩妹 (liao2 mei4), literally "to tease sisters", but 妹(子) on the internet is commonly used just to mean a pretty girl.
http://baike.baidu.com/item/%E6%92%A9%E5%A6%B9/19464048